# not getting correct result from slicing strings in python

Tags: python

I am slicing 24 digits long binary number into three 8digits long numbers.
Here is my code below:

```
def extract_number(number):
    number_in_string = str(number)
    red = number_in_string[:8]
    green = number_in_string[8:16]
    blue = number_in_string[16:24]
    return [int(red), int(green), int(blue)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(extract_number(101111010110011011100100))
```

The result i get from the terminal is

```
[10111101, 1100110, 11100100]
```

The problem occurs in the 2nd number. It's digit is not 8 digits long when I did number_in_string[8:16]. And I using slice function wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use slice function correctly

```
In [28]: str(101111010110011011100100)[8:16]
Out[28]: '01100110'
```

The second number has leading zero which is omitted once you convert string to integer.

```
In [29]: int('01100110')
Out[29]: 1100110
```

You use numbers represented in decimal base, but mention binary base. Is there a reason for this? I would like to recommend you to use binary base

```
def extract_number(number):
    number_in_string = bin(number)[2:]
    red = number_in_string[:8]
    green = number_in_string[8:16]
    blue = number_in_string[16:24]
    return [int(red, 2), int(green, 2), int(blue, 2)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(extract_number(0b101111010110011011100100))
```

The code above outputs

```
[189, 102, 228]
```

If you need binary representations of these numbers use builtin [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) function

Answer (score 1):

Try returning the strings as they are. Converting them to integers will remove any leading zeroes from the string, if present. Corrected code here-

```
def extract_number(number):
    number_in_string = str(number)
    red = number_in_string[:8]
    green = number_in_string[8:16]
    blue = number_in_string[16:24]
    return [red, green, blue]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(extract_number(101111010110011011100100))
```

Output-

```
['10111101', '01100110', '11100100']
```

Comment: Hey! I do not see any changes here 0_0

Comment: @Kahsn I don't see why you don't see any changes. Check the answer again. I have updated it with the output. Note, I am returning the **sliced strings** without casting them to **integers**.

Comment: Oh my bad. I totally missed the int() part. Gottcha.